# How to create a function that given a positive integer, returns a vector with the numbers multiples of 5 that exist?

Tags: r, function, vector

I have to create a `mult5` function that, given a positive integer, returns a vector with the numbers multiples of 5 that exist less than or equal to that number. For example, for the number 17, `mult5 (17)` should return the vector (0, 5, 10, 15). I can't use any type of loop or sapply / lapply.

I think i can do it with the seq function but I don't know how. That's what I've tried:

```
mult5 <- function(numero){
  modulo = numero %% 5 == 0
  seq = seq(from = 0, to = numero, by = modulo)
}
```

But I think I can't put variables inside the sequence function and throw me an error.
Can someone explain or tell me what I could do?

The test:

```
is.list(mult5(24)) == FALSE
all(mult5(24) == c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20))
check.not.command("for", mult5)
check.not.command("while", mult5)
```

I cant use for/while.

Error msg:

```
 Error in seq.default(from = 0, to = numero, by = modulo) : 
  invalid '(to - from)/by'
```

Comment: No need for the modulus. `seq(0, numero, by = 5)`

Comment: What's the outcome and the error message?

Comment: your error is because `numero %% 5 == 0` returns `TRUE/FALSE` which is not a valid value for the `by` argument in `seq`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `seq` function already has the behaviour you need if `numero` is not a multiple of 5, so you can streamline your code to:

```
mult5 <- function(numero){
  seq(from = 0, to = numero, by = 5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats mine example:

```
def check(number: int):
    lst = list(range(0, number, 5))
    print(lst)
```

Edited with @diggusbickus suggestion

Comment: list(range(0,number,5))

Comment: @diggusbickus You are right, more pythonic way